# CURL and PHP webservice

Tags: php, web-services, curl, soap, server

I have the following webservice:

```
<?php

class MySoapInterface
{
    public function getMessage($name)
    {
        return "Hello" . $name;
    }
}

$options = array(
    'uri' => 'http://localhost:8080/ImageGetter/main.php'
);

$server = new SoapServer(null, $options);

$server->setObject(new MySoapInterface());

$server->handle();
```

And I am trying to access the webservice via curl with:

```
curl --header "Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8" --header GET --data @test.xml http://localhost:8080/ImageGetter
```

```
<types>
    <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
      targetNamespace="http://localhost:8080/ImageGetter/main.php">
      <xs:element name="getMessage">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="name" type="tns:string"/>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="getMessageResponse">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="getMessageReturn" type="xs:string"/>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:schema>
  </types>
```

I am getting "Wrong version"
What am I doing wrong? I am sorry if thats easy but I'm really new on this